# How to get records sharing the same column values in one single row

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like this

| Tep | ID number | Date | Value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 22-09-2021 | 1.2 | X |
| XYZ | 2 | 22-10-2021 | 3.2 | X |
| ABC | 3 | 22-10-2021 | 3.2 | Y |
| WSH | 4 | 22-10-2021 | 3.2 | X |

I want the output like this

| Tep | ID number | Date | Value | type | ID number -1 | Value -1 | type -1 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 22-09-2021 | 1.2 | X | 3 | 3.2 | Y | 4.4 |

Basically I want the records with the same value in TEP in the same row.

Please can someone suggest how to do it?

Comment: What should happen if there are **more than two rows** with the same TEP value (or only one row)?

Answer (score 2):

If there are only ever two rows with the same TEP value, you could use something like:

```sql
select
  t1.tep, t1.id, t1.date, t1.value, t1.type
          t2.id, t2.date, t2.value, t2.type,
  t1.value + t2.value
from table t1
join table t2
where t1.tep = t2.tep
  and t1.id < t2.id
```

It joins the table to itself, matches on the TEP value and makes sure that the ID values are different.

Answer (score 0):

Quite straightforward using window functions, a bit verbose but I hope easy to read. `the_table` CTE is a mimic of the actual data table. No restriction on the number of rows with the same `tep` value.

```sql
with the_table (tep, id_number, tdate, value, type) as 
(
 values
 ('ABC', 1, '22-09-2021'::date, 1.2, 'X'),
 ('XYZ', 2, '22-10-2021', 3.2, 'X'),
 ('ABC', 3, '22-10-2021', 3.2, 'Y'),
 ('WSH', 4, '22-10-2021', 3.2, 'X')
)
SELECT tep, id_number, tdate, type, "id number -1", "value -1", "type -1", total 
from
(
 select 
  tep, id_number, tdate, type, 
  lead(id_number) over wa "id number -1",
  lead(value)     over wa "value -1",
  lead(type)      over wa "type -1",
  sum(value)      over wb total,
  count(*)        over wb cnt,
  row_number()    over wa pos 
 from the_table
 window wa as (partition by tep order by id_number),
        wb as (partition by tep)
) t
where cnt > 1 and pos = 1;
```